# Perforce: list all the files in current directory but not from subdirectories

Tags: perforce

In Perforce, I want to list all the files in the current directory but the result should not include the files from the subdirectories.

For example, if I have,

```
//depot/X/first.c  
//depot/X/second.c  
//depot/Y/third.c  
//depot/Z/fourth.c
```

The result of the command, when run for **//depot/X**, would contain **first.c** and **second.c** only.

The command,

```
p4 files //depot/X/...
```

will list all the files so it is of no use.

I tried with other wildcards like *, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Never mind. I was using csh and I found that for csh, I need to use "**" (with quotes). So, for the above example, p4 files //depot/X/"*" will return the required answer.

Comment: Yes, * is the right wildcard to use if you want to specify this directory only, not subdirectories.

Comment: Please edit the question (or add an answer below) with what you found out.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is： How to list all files and directories in specified directory not including the contents from sub directories.

And the command

```
p4 files //xxx/xxxx/"*"
p4 files //xxx/xxxx/'*'
p4 files //xxx/xxxx/*
```

These commands will just list the files in directory, but lost the sub directories.

If you want to get all sub directories name, you could use the p4 dirs

```
p4 dirs //xxx/xxxx/*
```

Then the sub directories will be printed in the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the command would be `p4 files //depot/X/*`, however, it seems in your case you are using the csh shell.  In that case, the * wildcard has to be quoted, e.g. `p4 files //depot/X/'*'`.